# Cannot move my bndtools osgi projects to another machine\computer

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, bndtools

I have a couple of bndtools projects(one being the interface and other being the implementation) in my workspace.

What is the best way to move both of these projects to a workspace in a different machine\computer?
I understand that directly copy pasting won't work but i still
1.Tried to copy paste the projects - didn't work
2.Tried importing project from eclipse - didn't work

Comment: Copy the project's dir to the new workspace, and import it using "import existing project". If this doesn't work; are you sure the other machine has the same version of bndtools etc?

Comment: i tried your suggestion first on a different workspace on the same machine(it works fine , except that i have to manually add a few bundled jars to the local repository which i think cannot be avoided). When i tried this on another computer , i could not even add any external bundled jars to the bnd.bnd file i.e. it does not let me drag and drop

Comment: Make sure the you use a compatible cnf project on the new machine. Any changes inside the repositories must also be done on the new machine. Easiest way is to export cnf and your projects simultaneously.